# Insert rows into different table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, insert, insert-select

I'm trying to re-map some data within my mysql database.

I want to move content within a table called `category_article` to another table called `article_tag`.

I want to move a single field (`article_id`) and add my own data for `tag_id`.

I currently have:

```
INSERT INTO article_tags (tag_id, article_id)
SELECT 3, article_id
FROM category_article
WHERE category_id = '7';
```

Obviously I know '3' is wrong in this context, so perhaps I need to set it as a variable?

I'm not sure how mysql works for things like this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If you want 3 as value then that's correct

Comment: Is right, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html

Comment: It looks like you have it right there, but if you are wanting the '3' to increment you can set the PK on the table you are inserting in to increment, then don't specify it on your insert.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like, and if you need to copy lots of data, you can use this approach:

Create a stored procedure that will perform the insertion of data for you:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Copy_From_Category_Article_To_Article_Tag`
(
      IN prm_tagid INT
    , IN prm_category_id VARCHAR(10)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO article_tags (tag_id, article_id)
    SELECT prm_tagid, article_id
    FROM category_article
    WHERE category_id = prm_category_id;
END
```

Then execute it with the parameters for the tag id and the category id of the records you want to copy:

```
CALL Copy_From_Category_Article_To_Article_Tag(3, '7');
```

The statement above can be execute multiple times in order if you prefer:

```
CALL Copy_From_Category_Article_To_Article_Tag(3, '7'); -- copy category 7 to tag 3
CALL Copy_From_Category_Article_To_Article_Tag(5, '1'); -- copy category 1 to tag 5
CALL Copy_From_Category_Article_To_Article_Tag(9, '4'); -- copy category 4 to tag 9
```

And so on...

Comment: What would be the advantage of that over a series of statements like:

INSERT INTO article_tags (tag_id, article_id) SELECT 44, article_id FROM category_article WHERE category_id = '7';
INSERT INTO article_tags (tag_id, article_id) SELECT 12, article_id FROM category_article WHERE category_id = '19';

and so on..

Apologies I can't figure out the formatting syntax to make that look more readable

Comment: I guess in your case it would depend.. Are you manually copying all this data? Do you ever need to store information about the data you copied? Are you simply running this in a MySQL tool such as Sequel Pro or PHPMyAdmin? One simple advantage would be simplicity of your code, in a case where you need to repeatedly change values; instead of changing in two separate, possibly far-from-each-other positions, this `might` appear easier since the parameters can be set beside each other. But if you need to track changes or modifications you make, you can include such statements inside a procedure too

Comment: You don't need a procedure for that: INSERT INTO article_tags (tag_id, article_id) SELECT CASE category_id WHEN 7 THEN 44 WHEN 19 THEN 12 END, article_id FROM category_article WHERE category_id IN(7,12); works just fine. You could also put the tag_id into the categories table temporarily and then use a join. As long as the fields you're selecting line up with the INSERT fields, you're good to go.